# What affects ordering in my set of pointers (specific example)

Tags: c++

In the test code below, the pointers are clearly being ordered by address in the set, as shown in the printout. What could change the ordering in the set, such that the the ids are not printed in order, without changing the order in which objects are inserted?

Can someone show an example by altering this code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

class Object {
    int id;
  public:
    void setId (int i) {id = i;}
    int getId() {return id;}
};

int main ()
{
  std::set<Object*> myset1;
  std::set<Object*> myset2;
  std::set<Object*>::iterator it;
  Object *obj;

  for (int i=1; i<=5; ++i){
    obj = new Object();
    obj->setId(i);
    myset1.insert(obj);
  }

  for (int i=1; i<=5; ++i){
    obj = new Object();
    obj->setId(i);
    myset2.insert(obj);
  }

  std::cout << "myset1 contains:";
  for (it=myset1.begin(); it!=myset1.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << ' ' << (*it)->getId() << "(" << (long long)*it << ")";
  std::cout << '\n';

  std::cout << "myset2 contains:";
  for (it=myset2.begin(); it!=myset2.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << ' ' << (*it)->getId() << "(" << (long long)*it << ")";
  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
myset1 contains: 1(24842256) 2(24842336) 3(24842416) 4(24842496) 5(24842576)
myset2 contains: 1(24842656) 2(24842736) 3(24842816) 4(24842896) 5(24842976)
```

Comment: With `obj->setId(5 - i);`, you will have `5(24842256) 4(24842336) 3(24842416) 2(24842496) 1(24842576)`). or even use `obj->setId(1 + ((3 * i) % 5));`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is somewhat nebulous in that it isn't clear whether you seek a comparator-change solution to a unstated problem, or simply want to know if it is possible for the same comparator and same insertion order to *not* generate the ordering you're seeing. Most other answers seem to be honing on the former; this one will address the latter.

The `std::set<>` container utilizes `std::less<>` by default for its comparator. For any pointer type, `std::less<>` provides a specialization that orders based on total memory ordering (as you've seen).

You're left entirely at the memory allocators mercy. For example, consider the following code change to your first loop:

```
char *tmp = new char[sizeof(Object)];

for (int i=1; i<=5; ++i){
    obj = new Object();
    obj->setId(i);
    myset1.insert(obj);
    if (i == 3)
        delete [] tmp; // open the hole up after the third insertion
}
```

On my rig (OS X 10.10.5), this gives the following output:

```
myset1 contains: 4(4296037184) 1(4296037200) 2(4296037264) 3(4296037328) 5(4296037440)
myset2 contains: 1(4296037504) 2(4296037568) 3(4296037632) 4(4296037696) 5(4296037760)
```

I can *speculate* what is causing this. That initial temporary allocation, once freed, adds a free block to the free-chain for the heap manager that is (not coincidentally) the perfect size for the next allocation (the 4th) consumed in the loop.

Dunno if that is what you were looking for, but the bottom line is you're code is indeed entirely at the mercy of the memory manager in dictating the addresses the objects occupy, and thusly their ordering in the set as a consequence.

Answer (score 0):

By default elements in set are sorted by pointers. There is no guarantee in which order you will get these pointers (yes, there is a chance that they will be in order, but no such guarantee). If you want always stable order, you need to add comparison functor. Another approach is to create vector and use Object pointers to elements of vector, they will be in order:

```
struct ObjectLess : public std::binary_function<Object, Object, bool> {
    bool operator()(const Object* lhs, const Object* rhs) const
    {
        return lhs->getId() < rhs->getId();
    }
};
```

Please not that I've added `const` to `getId`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

class Object {
    int id;
  public:
    void setId (int i) {id = i;}
    int getId() const {return id;}
};

struct ObjectLess : public std::binary_function<Object, Object, bool> {
    bool operator()(const Object* lhs, const Object* rhs) const
    {
        return lhs->getId() < rhs->getId();
    }
};

int main ()
{
  std::set<Object*, ObjectLess> myset1;
  std::set<Object*, ObjectLess> myset2;
  std::set<Object*, ObjectLess>::iterator it;
  Object *obj;

  for (int i=1; i<=5; ++i){
    obj = new Object();
    obj->setId(i);
    myset1.insert(obj);
  }

  for (int i=1; i<=5; ++i){
    obj = new Object();
    obj->setId(i);
    myset2.insert(obj);
  }

  std::cout << "myset1 contains:";
  for (it=myset1.begin(); it!=myset1.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << ' ' << (*it)->getId() << "(" << (long long)*it << ")";
  std::cout << '\n';

  std::cout << "myset2 contains:";
  for (it=myset2.begin(); it!=myset2.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << ' ' << (*it)->getId() << "(" << (long long)*it << ")";
  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
myset1 contains: 1(105690555281392) 2(105690555281360) 3(105690555281328) 4(105690555281296) 5(105690555281264)
myset2 contains: 1(105690555281232) 2(105690555281200) 3(105690555281168) 4(105690555281136) 5(105690555281104)
```

Comment: The question is *What could change the ordering in the set, such that the the ids are not printed in order*. Your answer does not address the question.

Comment: yes, but my question is: assuming I don't have a comparison function, what could possibly alter the ordering such that the objects are NOT stored as per their ids? I'm trying to understand the code I have, not make it better

Comment: @user1971455, amended answer

Answer (score 0):

You couldn't change `std::set`'s default behaviour unless providing a comparator for it, and define your own compare logic in it to control the order, such as:

```
struct MyCom {
    bool operator()(Object* o1, Object* o2) const { return o2->getId() < o1->getId(); }
};
```

and then

```
std::set<Object*, MyCom> myset2;
```

Now the elements in `myset2` will be sorted by the desc order of `Object::id`:

> myset2 contains: 5(144501624) 4(144501584) 3(144501544) 2(144501504) 1(144501464)

[LIVE](http://ideone.com/pf7wmH)

Comment: I don't want to change std::set's default behaviour. Currently, the objects remain ordered "by chance", but if I run this program 10 times they remain ordered every time.  I want to see an example of the chance  ordering being upset.